# $g(x) = |f(x)|$ is differentiable at $x_0$ iff $f'(x_0) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $x_0$, and $f(x_0) = 0$. Show that $g(x) = |f(x)|$ is differentiable at $x_0$ iff $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Given that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then, for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that if
$$
0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - L| < \varepsilon
$$

if $f'(x_0) = 0$ then

$$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - 0| < \varepsilon$$
$$ \implies |\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}| < \varepsilon$$

By the reverse triangle inequality we have that
$$|\frac{|f(x)| - |f(x_0)|}{x-x_0}| \leq |\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}| < \varepsilon$$

Then, $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies that
$$|\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0} - 0 | < \varepsilon$$

Therefore, $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

I'm having troubles when the hypothesis is that $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$, I would like to prove that $g'(x_0) = 0$ (I'm trying to prove it without using the fact that $g$ has a minimum at $x_0$). If I could prove that then I would have:

If $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g'(x_0) = 0$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist $\delta > 0$ such that if
$$0< |x - x_0|<\delta \implies |\frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x-x_0} -0| < \varepsilon$$
$$ \implies |\frac{|f(x)|}{x-x_0}| < \varepsilon$$
$$ \implies |\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x - x_0} - 0| < \varepsilon$$

Therefore $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ f $ is differentiable at $ x_0 \implies$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)\implies$$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{g(x)}{x-x_0}=|f'(x_0)|$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\frac{g(x)}{x-x_0}=-|f'(x_0)|$$

So,
$$g\text{ differentiable at } x_0\implies$$
$$|f'(x_0)|=-|f'(x_0)|\implies f'(x_0)=0$$

The converse is much easier.

Comment: Your question is a good one(+1)

Comment: Very nice answer